Staging Ground editor loses cursor (on mobile?)
Multiple times in the recent past, I have tried to edit Staging Ground posts, but had to give up because the editor basically lost my text cursor.
Sometimes, I am able to continue in the blind, and sometimes, e.g. double-clicking a word selects that word even though I can't see it; but most recently, I have simply had to give up and abandon my edits, because the cursor was invisible and could not be moved from the spot where I had last written or deleted something.
I have switched to the Markdown view, but even though it is less horrible when things actually work, it doesn't really help here.
On one post, when I knew what changes I wanted to make, and they were simple, I was able to proceed by saving the post when the cursor disappeared, then edit again, and after 2-3 saves I had changed all the things I wanted to change. But in the general case, this isn't practical (let alone acceptable), especially for nontrivial edits.
This is on an iPhone 12 Mini using Firefox.

For me, it typically moves to the beginning of the post when opening the text field/area.

Reported two years ago and never fixed and the editor is still mandatory for staging ground, what a joke: https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/378749/134300 https://github.com/StackExchange/Stacks-Editor/issues/206
